# Guide me to a dependable subtitling software that also hard-codes subtitles ('hardsubs')

Tags: 16.04, video, ffmpeg, subtitle, avidemux

I am in need.

After going through other queries, I believe that **avidemux** is not as stable as before and has to be 'built'. If not, please guide me as to how I can get the deb version.

My need is to hardcode subtitles onto a video. I have tried **Handbrake** already which doesn't suit the purpose. Is there an alternative?

Kindly note I need a software with a front-end. I am not adept in terminal language and it takes me time. And **WinFF**, based on **ffmpeg**, does not hardcode subtitles.

Windows I believe has several options. I would love a Linux version. This would really help me.

Thank you in advance and I hope I have been detailed.

Comment: Dear David, it is 16.04. Can you assist me? It will save me the trouble of looking at Mac/ Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a pre-built binary package of [Avidemux for Ubuntu 16.04 from the GetDeb repositories](http://www.getdeb.net/app/Avidemux%202.6):

1. [Set up the GetDeb repository](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/16.04/#how_to_install).
2. Don't forget to update the repository list (step 5 of the link above)! Use your favourite package manager or run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the package via the link title “Install this now” on the [GetDeb application page](http://www.getdeb.net/app/Avidemux%202.6) or

   > Install the application manually with the following commands:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-qt
   > ```

Comment: Thank you so much David. This has made me happy and charged up! There are many who are facing this problem, and they are not aware of repositories and other such details. It would be wonderful if this solution was well-known.