# Is there an updated solution for avidemux on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, avidemux

I saw this answer - [Guide me to a dependable subtitling software that also hard-codes subtitles](https://askubuntu.com/a/922618/234752), but the getdeb links seem to be broken or gone.

I also tried the appImage file for Linux here - [Download Avidemux latest release](https://www.fosshub.com/Avidemux.html), but it would not execute at all. (I did set the file properties to "executable".)

Also no results on Ubuntu package search.

So is there any currently available solution to run this on 16.04?

Comment: appimage files first have to be marked as executable before they will run.  You can right click the file and go to properties, then permissions and check the box that says "Allow executing the file as a program".  You can also do it in the terminal with just chmod u+x filename

Comment: @Gerowen Yes I did that but still no activity. Even iotop shows no disk activity when double-clicking from the desktop.

Comment: You could try executing it from the terminal to see if you get any kind of output; just run it like you would any other executable from the terminal:

./filename.AppImage

Comment: @Gerowen Then I get "bash: ./avidemux_2.7.1v2.appImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".

Comment: There is a PPA you can try: https://launchpad.net/~rebuntu16/+archive/ubuntu/avidemux+unofficial?field.series_filter=xenial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Avidemux on Ubuntu 16.04 as a flatpak package. Flatpak is a next-generation technology for building and distributing desktop applications on Linux that is supported in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. For earlier versions of Ubuntu flatpak support can be added from ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak.

To install Avidemux in Ubuntu 16.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak # required in 16.04 only, not in later releases
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.avidemux.Avidemux
flatpak run org.avidemux.Avidemux
```

The last command is the command to start Avidemux from the terminal. Avidemux can also be launched by clicking on its icon in the Dash.

Comment: How can I update avidemux to a newer version? According to docs I tried `flatpak update flathub org.avidemux.Avidemux` but got error `error: Invalid id flathub: Names must contain at least 2 periods`.

Comment: @user3169 Run `flatpak update org.avidemux.Avidemux` to update the Avidemux flatpak package. Don't include `flathub` in the command. It's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to update successfully. However, the current version 2.8.0 seems to have bugs. I see I can uninstall it, but how can I then install an older version (I was using 2.7.4) or 2.7.6 that I'm using on Windows?

Comment: Please read this answer: [Installing older flatpaks versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349197/)

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to use flatpak now. Problem I had in avidemux was in the settings though and not a bug.