# How can i permanently disable the "lock alpha channel" feature in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Ever since i upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and got whatever version of GIMP it gave me, I am constantly having to hit this button "lock alpha channel" to do anything with a pasted layer, including delete it, which is the most annoying part about it. But even though I selected in the options, that any settings i set should remain the way i set them, this particular option, keeps turning itself on. And I can't find any option that will stop it. If there is no possible way to rid myself of this feature, can someone at least tell me what version of gimp, doesn't have this feature (or bug I'd say) and how do i get that version, instead of the one Ubuntu automatically gives me.
[image]

Comment: On one occassion, I had already been unsuccessful in installing a previous version of Gimp. Nevertheless, I share the thread, maybe you find something useful in it, or maybe you are after a different version, which could maybe work: https://askubuntu.com/q/1349179/1157519

Comment: I also suggest: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?tags=gimp

Comment: https://www.gimp-forum.net/

Comment: Are you doing the steps after pasting the layer properly? When I paste a layer, it says floating selection, and the alpha channel is locked as it should be. Then you need to click either "To new layer" or "Anchor layer". Pasting it into an empty GIMP is also fine. Once that is done, the floating selection turns into a real layer and the alpha channel is unlocked

Comment: Another idea: it can happen that Gimp saves the state of that tool as a user-setting, or as a last-used setting, and it somehow persists through multiple sessions. I had a similarly annoying experience where the initial state of selection tools were stuck in "subtract from selection" mode, through a long time. A factory reset could be an idea.

Comment: I assigned no shortcuts. Unless ctrl+V does it. Because as soon as i hit paste, it comes up locked. This is not the way it used to work. In the past I was unaware if there even was a lock alpha channel button, because i never had to use it. I could paste, and if i changed my mind, hit delete and it was gone. The other thing i can't do with that lock on is use the eraser on a floating section. I just want it to stay off, like it used to be for the several years i had been using it in the past.

Answer (score -1):

This is the way it is supposed to work (and in case you wonder, I checked on a Gimp 2.8 and it also behaves like this).

In Gimp 2.10, there is an `Edit > Paste as > New layer in place` that directly pastes the clipboard as a new layer over its initial position. The alpha channel of that pasted layer is not locked.

The shortcut for this operation is `Ctrl-Alt-V` so either you forgot that you were depressing Alt, or you redefined the shortcut.

Comment: I never touch shortcuts. And i never used to paste as new layer with a short cut. Usually if i did want a to paste to a new layer, I'd paste it first and the select, with the mouse, move to new layer. I don't know what my last version of GIMP was, but it must be pre-2.8 if 2.8 was still the same thing. My old PC won't take power anymore so i can't look up what version it used (whatever was the last version they gave me in ubuntu 16 i suppose). Also, i don't care if it's "the way it is supposed to work " I don't want it to work that way. I want it to work the old way.

Comment: Well, I have at least partly answered your question: if you want the behavior you think you remember, you would need to check back to at least 2.6. But Gimp 2.8 is already 12 years old. Also, you don't need to unlock the layer to delete it.

Comment: Yes i do need to unlock it. If i press ctrl+v, paste, and press delete, it does nothing until i uncheck the lock. I've started using ctrl+z to undo instead of delete, because of it. I don't know software so much, but it seems people can patch and mod just about anything, to do anything, so surely there's a way to disable this feature.

Comment: Misunderstood "delete" at this point. I thought you wanted to remove the layer completely, not empty the contents.